# How do I use a frontmatter variable as a variable in Jekyll/Liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I tried using square brackets like this:

`{{ [my_variable] }}`

... which is not working. The square brackets are only working together with other text in the curly brackets:

`{{ some_other_text.[my_variable] }}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a hook / plugin as described here:

https://github.com/gemfarmer/jekyll-liquify

http://acegik.net/blog/ruby/jekyll/plugins/howto-nest-liquid-template-variables-inside-yaml-front-matter-block.html

... still wonder why `{{ [my_variable] }}` is not possible in liquid/jekyll...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the square brackets.
If your frontmatter looks like this:

```
---
my_variable: foo
---
```

Then you inject the variable like this: `{{ page.my_variable }}`.
Notice the `page.` prefix before the variable name.

For more information, look at the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/#custom-variables).

Comment: ... just saw your answer, thanks. Maybe i didn't express very well, for a more complicated scenario i need something like that:

Comment: ... just saw your answer, thanks. Maybe i didn't express very well, for a more complicated scenario i need something like that:


---
my_variable: site.title
---


and if i use `{{ page.my_variable  }}` i want to print my site title, not site.title .. and i can't use   `{{ site.title  }}`  directly, because i build a more complex scenario with cloudcannon, which makes me select other variables through variables, similar to `{{ some_other_text.[my_variable] }}`